# Does it make sense to implement Facebook auth as an ASP.NET Forms auth custom membership provider?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, forms-authentication

I'm currently developing a web application that will use Facebook as a authentication service. Does it make sense to implement it as an ASP.NET Forms Authentication custom membership provider? While I made my research, I didn't come across any concrete significant advantage of using the Forms Authentication. However, it instinctively seems to me as a good thing to do, because aside from creating a completely custom implementation of authentication using Facebook, I didn't find any extensibility point inside ASP.NET where I could plug in the Facebook auth behavior.

Can you then tell me whether the Forms Authentication is a good idea or not. And if not, is there any other way than completely custom code (I'd like to avoid managing the session cookies, loading the current user, etc. manually).

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3, Entity Framework and I'd like to avoid the Facebook C# SDK (the extensive use of dynamic types is a bit of a turnoff for me :-) ).

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple answer is to use .NET 4.5 oAuth templates, they are incredibly easy to link Facebook up to forms authentication.

http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/videos/oauth-in-the-default-aspnet-45-templates

However you may struggle to find a decent server if you are planning on releasing immediately. In a couple of months plenty of servers will support .NET 4.5.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this option and the project is not close to release, so the lack of 4.5 hosting is not a problem (plus I'm thinking about using Azure for hosting where it shouldn't be an issue anyway).

Comment: Azure is an excellent choice, can't recommend it enough. Web deploy is just so easy! Azure doesn't currently support 4.5, but should be expected very soon.

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth templates work for both v4.0 and v4.5 so you can publish them onto a server today itself :)

Comment: Is that true? can you give a link to back this up?